# Early Google Drive access to test applications?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to add Google Drive integration to an application immediately.  Is there a means to create or access some type of test account?

I have requested Google Drive on both my personal and application Google accounts, both of these requests appear to have been wait-listed.

The application Google account has both the Drive API and Drive SDK services enabled for this application, and the Drive SDK section has been configured.

Might there be a way I can gain immediate access as a developer?

Answer (score 6):

There's no early Google Drive access for developers, but requests are being approved as we speak, so it shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an apps account, it is immediate. It worked for me. I think they are rolling out to gmail accounts at a later stage.

Comment: Nope. I tried to set it up through my Apps management console, and it gave me the same "not ready" message as when I tried to get going with my regular Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but you may get access faster if you pay to upgrade your storage to 25GB. I've gotten access to Google Drive two hours after I bought the storage upgrade.